# Unsure how to approach json php mysql integration

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Let's say for sake of argument I have:

```
<select id="lvl1">
</select>
<div id="lvl2">
    <select id="lvl2a">
    <select id="lvl2b">
    <input text id="lvl2c">
</div>
<select id="lvl3">
</select>
```

in `file1.php` and I would like to populate `<select id="lvl3">` with the results of a query which would essentially look like:

```
SELECT * FROM lvl1 WHERE fld_a = lvl2a AND fld_b = lvl2b AND fld_c = lvl2c
```

The snag is `lvl2` is created dynamically in an external js file (`file2.js`) based on what the user chooses in `lvl1`. From everything I have seen it would seem I want to use JSON for this but how would I call a PHP function located in `file3.php` from an external js file, `file2.js` and return those results as an array to populate `lvl3` in `file1.php`?

Hopefully I have explained myself well enough. Thank you in advance.

Comment: selects and divs inside a select? You know what you're doing?

Comment: I do, I was going without the ending tags _assuming_ ppl would see it was shorthand just to get the idea across. I would also never name something lvl1. But I fixed it to make things more clear.

Comment: Look up AJAX examples [like this one from W3](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) or check out [Jquery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: look at "bookmarklet" examples; the communication methodbeetween the server and bookmarlet, it's what you ask for

Comment: @bill - aah. To succinctly answer, you may want to use jquery $.ajax making sure to pass dataType as "json" to pass select info on change to your script and serve back the necessary object. php will encode a key value array with json_encode. But to clarify, this site is often very literal so shorthand will almost always result in unwanted comments and probably less attention because a question too far outside of reasonable code syntax may look like more trouble than it's worth and you might not get any answers.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wFuqwctP
this might help you, i did that few days ago

Comment: @bluepicaso very useful I will definitely check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to refactor how your markup is generated in order to get this to work. Here's how I would do it:

1. `lvl1` is spit out from your PHP script when the page loads.
2. After the user chooses something in `lvl1`, you fire off an AJAX request back to the server with what they chose.
3. The server responds with the markup for `lvl2` which you inject into the page.
4. If needed, do the same after the user selects something from `lvl2` to fetch the content of `lvl3`.
5. Finally, submitting the form would relay all the selected data to your form processing script, where you will validate the responses and do whatever else it is that you're doing.

That should be enough to get you going.

Comment: This is kind of what I'm shooting towards however once the user makes a choice on `lvl3` I would be displaying some more relevant info but I see what you are saying. I guess AJAX is more what I need to look into rather than JSON alone.

Comment: Right, AJAX is how you'll send/receive data. JSON is the dialect you'll be using.